# Pycharm not updating pacakages

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to Python and PyCharm. I am trying to update a few packages but I am unable to do so, it throws me the same error:

Error: Traceback[image]

Comment: Have you tried proposed solution, i.e running it from system terminal?

Comment: I don't have sudo access in the terminal

Comment: try the same `pip` command by appending `--user` to it (without `sudo`)

Comment: Do I have to go into a specific directory to do this? because in home directory it says pip is not installed

Comment: I am not very comfortable with using the terminal and I do not know which directory to go  to, and where this will be installed, and which version of python will this new pip be associated with and which virtual environment this will be associated with as well

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a virtual environment in shell, updating pip in that venv and then firing pycharm within that venv through the shell. Then in the project interpreter, I chose the same virtual environment as the one created/ existing.